# How to create an edit profile page like Google+?

Tags: google-plus

We've got a directory that we want to modernise in terms of usability and coding. We've incorporated a lot of quite cool elements but one element we want to use is the way in which you can edit your profile on Google+.

How can we create something similar?

For instance, we want to include the following when the page is in it's editing state:

1. When each sub section is hovered over we want the whole box to change color. So it's clear your editing the section.
2. On clicking the box, we want the text to be editable with save and cancel options.
3. Once the user is happy, click done to save the overall changes on the page.

How can this be done? What coding languages would be needed?

Comment: If this is a web page, then you use css and javascript.

Comment: Is that what Google have used?

Comment: You're missing some core detail, like platform (web, desktop, embedded system, etc.) and what you mean by "directory".

Comment: Since it's the web, I imagine so. What other choices are there?

Comment: It's a web page. Even if they used complex frameworks and abstractions, at lower level everything is about (x)html, css and javascript. Your best bet is having a good knowledge of the basis, and then help yourself with some js framework like jquery

Comment: It's for web, an online profile of a list of companies. I kinda guessed it maybe a combination of those languages. I dunno, because it was google I assumed it may be something more complicated!!

Comment: It won't be easy, probably a lot of work, but it is css and javascript.

Comment: @Marcelo - how is this different than Matt Ellen's response?

Comment: @Jeff This was not a response, just a comment to Rob's "I assumed it may be something more complicated". Read it as: "It is css and javascript, **but** it will not be easy and it will take a lot of work." Better?

Comment: Hire a decent web developer. They'll know what to do.

Comment: Too broad a question for StackOverflow, despite having been migrated from Programmers: somewhere like http://ux.stackexchange.com/ might yield better answers.

Comment: Give me an invitation and I will tell you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'scriptaculous ajax framework'. It does exactly the same.. I have tested it and it works great...

Its called In-place editor. Its single line as well as multi-line..

Get the code here http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/ajax-inplaceeditor/

Answer (score 1):

> When each sub section is hovered over we want the whole box to change
>   color. So it's clear your editing the section.

In HTML/CSS using the `:hover` pseudo class: http://jsfiddle.net/sc26u/

```
.profileSection:hover { background: #333; color: #fff }
```

> On clicking the box, we want the text to be editable with save and
>   cancel options.
>
> Once the user is happy, click done to save the overall changes on the
>   page.

JavaScript to manipulate content, AJAX for save